# Xunit doesn't activate Sql trigger

Tags: c#, .net, xunit.net

I am trying to unit test SQL trigger behaviour with Xunit.

I have one trigger who modify the date of my column “LastUpdate” in my client’s table. This trigger is activating every time something modifies the table.

The trigger work correctly if I modify the data manually or when I use the application but when I try to unit test the behaviour it does not work. it is like the unit Test does not activate trigger.

Is there a way to force the activation of a SQL trigger with Xunit?
thanks in advance for your answer

**Edit**

Unit Test

```
public async Task Insert_Should_InsertSomething()
{
        var shop = await DbContext.shops.FirstAsync();

        DateTime shopModificationTime = shops.ModificationDate;
        const string clientName = "InsertedClient";

        var nbClientsBefore = await DbContext.Clients.CountAsync();

        await _service.InsertAsync(new ClientViewModelInput
        {
            Name = clientName,
            ShopId = shops.Id
        }); 

        (await DbContext.Clients.CountAsync()).Should().Be(nbClientsBefore + 1);
        DbContext.Clients.Count(z => z.Name == clientName).Should().Be(1);

        var sh2 = await DbContext.shops.FirstAsync(a => a.Id ==shops.Id);
        sh2.ModificationDate.Should().BeAfter(shopModificationTime);
        (shops.ModificationDate - DateTime.Now).Seconds.Should().BeLessThan(1);
}
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [shp].[trg_Client_InsertUpdateDelete]
ON [shp].[Client]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE shp.shop
    SET ModificationDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE id IN (SELECT i.ShopId
                 FROM inserted i
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT d.ShopId
                 FROM deleted d)
END
```

Comment: With no code and no details there is no way for anyone but you to diagnose this. XUnit does not have a special "do not fire triggers done in tests when they try to update" mode, so whatever is going wrong likely falls squarely on the shoulders of code you don't show.

Comment: 1) In this code, what is `shops`? Is this a typo for `shop` or an unseen field? 2) Your test scenario appears incomplete, in that it's missing the setup code. In what state is `DbContext.shops` at the beginning of the test, and how do you ensure this? For this test to work you have to ensure `shops.ModificationDate` is guaranteed to lie before whatever `GETDATE()` will be after the insert happens. The best way to do this is to give it a fixed, extreme value like `2000-01-01`. Tests should ideally not depend on timing of any kind.